# Detect overlapping Ovals/Ellipses in an Image - Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect multiple overlapping ovals in an image. The ovals are always of 2 colors namely yellow and red. I would want the output containing the x, y , angle and the center of the oval as output using python.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

I tried to seperate the ovals using image segmentation from Opencv. Now I would like to get the axis details of each ovals.
I have attached the image I used for testing and the partial code for image segmentation.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('SamplePaintImage.png')
original = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([22, 93, 0], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([45, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I expect the following as the output:
center.x, center.y, width, height and the angle information

Image:
[SampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGu9A.png)

Comment: Can you add your image 'SamplePaintImage.png', please?

Comment: Sorry, forgot it. Now I have uploaded the sample image.

Comment: The circles on the left can be detected using cv2.HoughCircles(mask, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.6, 50). For the overlapping ellipses I have no solution.